# Regex pattern with no special characters at the beginning and end. but Within a string is fine

Tags: regex

I have to implement below rule for a particular string.

field shall be populated and shall contain up to 52 alphanumerical characters. Four special characters are allowed ":", ".",  "-", " _" .  Special characters are not allowed at the beginning or the end.

I tried pattern [0-9A-Za-z:.-_] to include alphanumeric and 4 special characters but I am not sure how to make sure they do not appear at the beginning or end of the string. For example "Hello:123Howareyou" is valid but ":hello58475howareu" is invalid.

This pattern does not help [0-9A-Za-z:.-*] to include alphanumeric and special chars and (^(:.-*)) beginning of string should not start with these special chars and ((:.-_)$) end of string should not end with these special chars. How do I take care of " Special characters are not allowed at the beginning or the end." this part.

thanks
pash

Comment: This works fine for all but not - special character. For example  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9A-Za-z]+[0-9A-Za-z:.-_]*[0-9A-Za-z]+$"); this returns false for "hello-howareu" but returns true for "hello_howareu"

Answer (score 0):

Add regex for alphanumeric only for beginning and ending:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z]+[0-9A-Za-z:.\-_][0-9A-Za-z]+$
```

Or shorter version

```
^[\w]+[\w:.\-_][\w]+$
```

Comment: This works fine for all but not - special character. For example  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9A-Za-z]+[0-9A-Za-z:.-_]*[0-9A-Za-z]+$"); this returns false for "hello-howareu" but returns true for "hello_howareu"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w:.-]{0,50][a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Where `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

This will match strings up to 52 character long and at least 2 character long.

If you want to match at least one character:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[\w:.-]{0,50][a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```